# Hard evidence that Linux is more stable than windows?

Tags: windows, linux, performance, stability

I am trying to convince management to switch from SQL Server, to MySQL on Linux.
This is very much a windows house, and management seems very wary of using Linux.

Can anyone provide hard facts showing Linux is more stable, higher performance than
windows for running a DB server? And any other advantages?

Also, nobody here knows how to administer a Linux server, to the resistance is sociological as well as technical.

Thanks!

Comment: Let's sum it up. You don't have any proof that Linux + MySQL is better than Windows + SQL Server and what is more people have experience with the latter but not with the former and on top of it all people just don't want to migrate.

Then why for Google's sake do you want to change stuff?

Comment: This is ironic. If **you** don't know any such facts, why do you want to convince them to switch? Your motivation seems purely sociological. Maybe you need to learn how to play their game and stop trying to get them to play yours.

Comment: sociological is the wrong word. It could be instead "ideological". But we know that in business ideology is not enough, so he's searching for technical or whatever reasons to convince them.

Comment: Even if Linux were more stable than Windows (and I believe this or I wouldn't be using Linux), it doesn't follow that MySQL is more stable than SQL Server. And, given that no-one there knows diddly squat about Linux, whey _should_ they convert? It sounds like a huge risk for unknown (possibly dubious) benefits.

Comment: @Stilgar, @IVlad:
People who have used unix and windows systems know from their own experience that unix systems are generally much more stable than windows (I haven't met a single person experienced with both who would say otherwise). While this is generally true, you need hard proofs to convince other people to switch - personal experience doesn't look nice on paper :). Especially to management types :).

Comment: The time used to be when I would have my Unix desktops and servers stay up for weeks or months at a time and my Windows desktops rebooted one or more times per day.  I didn't even have Windows servers because I thought I couldn't trust them.  Now our Windows and Unix systems are rebooted about the same frequency -- once per month, sometimes more, but for scheduled patching -- and rarely go down on their own.  Generally I find that the services (software) need more care and feeding than the hardware/OS.

Comment: Though I do agree that if nobody at this shop has any experience with Unix, switching isn't necessarily a great idea. The costs of running inferior software are probably much smaller than the costs of retraining the admins (and any mistakes they make before they get enough experience with new soft).

Comment: @slacker - I'd be interested in knowing what versions of Windows you're talking about.  I've done both Windows and Unix and with W2K3 and onward don't see very many OS issues that cause unscheduled downtime.  I'm not an MS fan, but while your experience jibes with my past experience, it doesn't match up with my current experience.

Comment: @slacker - I never made any statement about which one is much more stable, I merely called the OP's post ironic, which it is. Assuming you are right, the OP should know the reasons he's trying to get management to switch. As the question stands right now, it seems like he has no good arguments for switching, hence my comment.

Answer (score 23):

Facts

1. It is a 'windows' house
2. They have good experience with MS Windows and SQL Server
3. They have no experience in *nix administration

Conclusion

Forget it. Even if you found prove that Linux+MySQL is more stable or more performant, then there would still be enough good arguments to **not** change the environment.

Comment: +1: I totally agree. One should keep focussed on real problems instead of ideology.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to convince yourself :)

Have a read here https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1054385.html

Comment: The source is really autdated. 2003? Come one that's ages in IT.

Comment: You're totally right I didn't notice that. But either way - a quick Google search will find you lots of articles weighing in the pros and cons of either server.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nowadays I don't think it's about stability anymore - that argument was a big marketing tactic for Linux. The biggest difference is the fact that Windows + SQL Server is not free, and actually quite expensive.

I think your best option would be to get Ubuntu installed on a machine and let them have a play with it and see how they like it.

But your biggest argument would be price...

And I do sympathise with you - I'm not a fan of Microsoft, and agree that going Linux + MySQL is better, but like others said, they are already used to what they have, so it'll be hard to convince them otherwise.

Also, not sure how big this company is, but if it's big, then they won't care about the money saved...

Comment: This is a very biased answer.

Comment: The cost of software licenses actually is quite irrelevant for larger companies. It is a small drop in the ocean of maintenance costs. And notice we are not talking about a desktop system here. The question was about a **server**.

Comment: @slacker: I don't agree. Software licenses (e.g. Oracle) can be **very** expensive, especially when you have thousands of servers. I've done enough cost studies to know that this is not irrelevant.