# MySQL vs SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cluster-computing

I am interested in people's opinions on MySQL vs SQL Server. Our database is fairly simple;
no stored procedures, and we use NHibernate as our ORM layer. I would like to make a case for switching from SQL Server to MySQL cluster on Linux. We need an enterprise level, clustered
DB with failover and load balancing. Any opinions pro or con would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is your consideration choosing MySQL in the first place?

Comment: Poll-type questions, because they don't have a real answer, should be community wiki by convention.

Comment: @tvanfosson, it's not pool-type question imho. He specified what DB engine should do.

Comment: @eugeneK - as it stands, it's asking for opinions, not a list of technical differences.  To me that makes it more of a beauty contest.  If it asked what the technical differences are that would favor using one or the other in an "enterprise level, clustered DB with failover and load balancing," that would be different.

Comment: This seems pretty much the same as your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174615/hard-evidence-that-linux-is-more-stable-than-windows-closed) and once again *you* don't seem to have any reason for wanting to switch. Do you actually have extensive experience with modern iterations of both platforms? You might get better answers if you can justify your own reason for wanting to switch.

Answer (score 1):

What scenario of failover/load balancing are you considering?  Are you [considering HAProxy](http://www.alexwilliams.ca/blog/2009/08/10/using-haproxy-for-mysql-failover-and-redundancy/)?

Comment: Thanks! very useful link. We don't have a detailed scenario for how failover/load balancing will work, other than the basic: failover fried server, and balance load over multiple servers.  The issue with master slave is replication latency, since it is asynchronous.
Also, we would need to split the reads and writes. Which is possible, since we have NHibernate layer.  MySQL cluster is synchronous, and load balanced, so this is why I am looking at it. SQL Server has no load balanced cluster solution.